# React Swiper setThumbsSwiper on multiple Swiper

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, react-swiper

I'm currently following an example of Thumb Gallery from the examples:
[Thumb Gallery Example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/k3cyyc). Here's the code of App.jsx:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/free-mode';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/thumbs';

import './styles.css';

// import required modules
import { FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs } from 'swiper/modules';

export default function App() {
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        style={{
          '--swiper-navigation-color': '#fff',
          '--swiper-pagination-color': '#fff',
        }}
        spaceBetween={10}
        navigation={true}
        thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
        modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
      <Swiper
        onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
        spaceBetween={10}
        slidesPerView={4}
        freeMode={true}
        watchSlidesProgress={true}
        modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
        className="mySwiper2"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```

I followed the example and it worked as expected. However, in my case. I want some SwiperSlides from `mySwiper2`, then add them into a separate Swiper(third one) with the same callback `onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}`. For some reason, only the third Swiper worked, and it didn't set the correct thumbsSwiper as it supposed to. Why is the second one not working? Is there a solution to this? I'll appreciate any kind of helps. thanks :)